# CNN compiling error : Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize,

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I just try to build up VGG-19 Model by myself, but every time I try to compile, the error rise, though it works clearly on Alexnet. please let me know the problem.

### Setting

CPU : AMD RYZEN 2700x
GPU : RTX 2080
OS : Window 10
CUDA : 10.0
Tensorflow version : Tensorflow-2.0.0beta1
Working tools : Jupyter lab
Time : 3 AM
Climate : rainy
Feel : gloomy :(

### Code

```py
import tensorflow as tf  
from tensorflow import keras  
from tensorflow.keras import layers  
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from functools import partial  
import skimage.io as io  
import numpy as np  

EPOCH = 5  
BATCH = 32  
Learning_rate = 0.0001  

leaky_relu = partial(keras.activations.relu, alpha=0.1)  

def to_float(image, label) :  
    float_image = image/255  
    return (float_image, label)  

data, info = tfds.load('cifar10',as_supervised=True,with_info=True)  

train, test = data.get('train'), data.get('test')  
train_data = train.map(to_float).shuffle(10000).batch(BATCH).prefetch(3)  
test_data = test.map(to_float).batch(BATCH).prefetch(4)  

sample_batch = next(iter(train_data))[0]  
print(io.imshow_collection(io.concatenate_images(np.array(sample_batch))))  


class VGG19(tf.keras.Model) :  
    def __init__(self) :  
        super(VGG19, self).__init__()  
        self.conv1_1 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 64,  
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),  
                                      strides=(1,1),  
                                      padding='same',  
                                      activation=leaky_relu)  
        self.conv1_2 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 64,  
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),  
                                      strides=(1,1),  
                                      padding='same',  
                                      activation=leaky_relu)  
        self.pool1 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),  
                                      strides=(2,2),  
                                      padding='same')  


        self.conv2_1 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 128,  
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),  
                                      strides=(1,1),  
                                      padding='same',  
                                      activation=leaky_relu)  
        self.conv2_2 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 128,  
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),  
                                      strides=(1,1),  
                                      padding='same',  
                                      activation=leaky_relu)  
        self.pool2 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),  
                                      strides=(2,2),  
                                      padding='same')  


        self.conv3_1 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 256,  
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),  
                                      strides=(1,1),  
                                      padding='same',  
                                      activation=leaky_relu)  
        self.conv3_2 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 256,  
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),  
                                      strides=(1,1),  
                                      padding='same',  
                                      activation=leaky_relu)  
        self.conv3_3 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 256,  
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),  
                                      strides=(1,1),  
                                      padding='same',  
                                      activation=leaky_relu)  
        self.conv3_4 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 256,  
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),  
                                      strides=(1,1),  
                                      padding='same',  
                                      activation=leaky_relu)  
        self.pool3 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),  
                                      strides=(2,2),  
                                      padding='same')  


        self.conv4_1 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 512,
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),
                                      strides=(1,1),
                                      padding='same',
                                      activation=leaky_relu)
        self.conv4_2 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 512,
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),
                                      strides=(1,1),
                                      padding='same',
                                      activation=leaky_relu)
        self.conv4_3 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 512,
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),
                                      strides=(1,1),
                                      padding='same',
                                      activation=leaky_relu)
        self.conv4_4 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 512,
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),
                                      strides=(1,1),
                                      padding='same',
                                      activation=leaky_relu)
        self.pool4 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),
                                      strides=(2,2),
                                      padding='same')


        self.conv5_1 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 512,
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),
                                      strides=(1,1),
                                      padding='same',
                                      activation=leaky_relu)
        self.conv5_2 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 512,
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),
                                      strides=(1,1),
                                      padding='same',
                                      activation=leaky_relu)
        self.conv5_3 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 512,
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),
                                      strides=(1,1),
                                      padding='same',
                                      activation=leaky_relu)
        self.conv5_4 = layers.Conv2D(filters = 512,
                                      kernel_size=(3,3),
                                      strides=(1,1),
                                      padding='same',
                                      activation=leaky_relu)
        self.pool5 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),
                                      strides=(2,2),
                                      padding='same')


        self.flat6 = layers.Flatten()
        self.fc6 = layers.Dense(units=4096,
                                activation=leaky_relu)
        self.drop6 = layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)


        self.fc7 = layers.Dense(units=4096,
                                activation=leaky_relu)
        self.drop7 = layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)


        self.fc8 = layers.Dense(units=10,
                                activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)

    def call(self, inputs):
            x = self.conv1_1(inputs)
            x = self.conv1_2(x)
            x = self.pool1(x)

            x = self.conv2_1(x)
            x = self.conv2_2(x)
            x = self.pool2(x)

            x = self.conv3_1(x)
            x = self.conv3_2(x)
            x = self.conv3_3(x)
            x = self.conv3_4(x)
            x = self.pool3(x)

            x = self.conv4_1(x)
            x = self.conv4_2(x)
            x = self.conv4_3(x)
            x = self.conv4_4(x)
            x = self.pool4(x)

            x = self.conv5_1(x)
            x = self.conv5_2(x)
            x = self.conv5_3(x)
            x = self.conv5_4(x)
            x = self.pool5(x)

            x = self.flat6(x)
            x = self.fc6(x)
            x = self.drop6(x)

            x = self.fc7(x)
            x = self.drop7(x)

            output = self.fc8(x)

            return output


VGG19_model = VGG19()

my_loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

VGG19_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(Learning_rate),
                loss = my_loss,
                metrics = ['accuracy'],
               )

VGG19_model.fit(train_data, epochs = EPOCH, verbose=2)
```

### Error Message

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-1e291c11711c> in <module>
      4                )
      5 
----> 6 VGG19_model.fit(train_data, epochs = EPOCH, verbose=2)

~\Anaconda3\envs\cuda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    641         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    642         workers=workers,
--> 643         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    644 
    645   def evaluate(self,

~\Anaconda3\envs\cuda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    692         shuffle=shuffle,
    693         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
--> 694         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
    695 
    696   def evaluate(self,

~\Anaconda3\envs\cuda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    262 
    263       is_deferred = not model._is_compiled
--> 264       batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
    265       if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    266         batch_outs = [batch_outs]

~\Anaconda3\envs\cuda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
    916       self._update_sample_weight_modes(sample_weights=sample_weights)
    917       self._make_train_function()
--> 918       outputs = self.train_function(ins)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    919 
    920     if reset_metrics:

~\Anaconda3\envs\cuda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3508         value = math_ops.cast(value, tensor.dtype)
   3509       converted_inputs.append(value)
-> 3510     outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
   3511 
   3512     # EagerTensor.numpy() will often make a copy to ensure memory safety.

~\Anaconda3\envs\cuda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    570       raise TypeError("Keyword arguments {} unknown. Expected {}.".format(
    571           list(kwargs.keys()), list(self._arg_keywords)))
--> 572     return self._call_flat(args)
    573 
    574   def _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\cuda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args)
    669     # Only need to override the gradient in graph mode and when we have outputs.
    670     if context.executing_eagerly() or not self.outputs:
--> 671       outputs = self._inference_function.call(ctx, args)
    672     else:
    673       self._register_gradient()

~\Anaconda3\envs\cuda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args)
    443             attrs=("executor_type", executor_type,
    444                    "config_proto", config),
--> 445             ctx=ctx)
    446       # Replace empty list with None
    447       outputs = outputs or None

~\Anaconda3\envs\cuda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     if any(ops._is_keras_symbolic_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\cuda\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)
```

### UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.

**(0) Unknown:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.**
     [[node vg_g19_2/conv2d_32/Conv2D (defined at :6) ]]
    [[Func/Adam/gradients_2/vg_g19_2/dropout_5/cond_grad/If/then/_22/input/_75/_64]]

**(1) Unknown:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.**
     [[node vg_g19_2/conv2d_32/Conv2D (defined at :6) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_10115]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph -> keras_scratch_graph

Comment: Did you install cuDNN? ( https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn ) Is your Nvidia driver version > 410.x? Make sure you meet all of the requirements ( https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing will be to check if compatible CUDA, cuDNN drivers are installed correctly. Then you may try gpu memory resources management by allowing gpu memory growth.

**allow_growth** option, attempts to allocate only as much GPU memory based on runtime allocations: it starts out allocating very little memory, and as Sessions get run and more GPU memory is needed, it extend the GPU memory region needed by the TensorFlow process.

To know more see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth
You can try Allowing GPU memory growth with:

```py
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

Comment: Since I use tensorflow2.0.0-beta1, the answer you gave didn't work. however I found similar thing in tensorflow2.0 tutorial  

`gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')`  

And it did work finally!! Thanks for your help :)